# react.js jsx watch not generating files

Tags: reactjs, file-watcher

I'm new to React.js and I want to use .jsx files for development.
I have installed the react-tools and ran the command below as mentioned in the docs.

```
jsx --watch src/ build/
```

The watcher is running and noticing my changes in my .jsx files. However, it does not generate any .js files.

I'm receiving the following output:

```
[]
app.jsx changed; rebuilding...
[]
app.jsx___jb_bak___ changed; rebuilding...
app.jsx___jb_bak___ changed; rebuilding...
app.jsx changed; rebuilding...
```

The command line was ran under admin privileges and it was able to create the build directory by itself. How can I fix this so that it generates the js files or even troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I wanted to let you know that react-tools has been [dreprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html) in favour of [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/jsx/)

Comment: Thanks! That's already a big help to me. I used it because that's what is present on the React.js documentation pages: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve my issues by switching over to [babel](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/02/23/babel-loves-react/) as mentioned by mfirry.
The [React.js documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) is currently outdated as it still includes react-tools: